# Read data from a website using Nashorn

Tags: javascript, java, nashorn

I want to retrieve data from a website using Nashorn script engine

I have the java code where I can retrieve data from a sample website template.

Now I want to call that java file from java script file.

following is the code:

**JAVA CODE(Nsample.java):**

```
package sample;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;


public class Nsample
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
String output  = getUrlContents("https://freewebsitetemplates.com/");
System.out.println(output);
}



public static String getUrlContents(String theUrl)
{
StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();


try
{

  URL url = new URL(theUrl);


  URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();


  BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new 
  InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));

  String line;


  while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
  {
    content.append(line + "\n");
  }
   bufferedReader.close();
  }
  catch(Exception e)
  {
  e.printStackTrace();
  }
  return content.toString();
  }
 }
```

**JAVASCRIPT code:(sample.js)**

```
var n = Java.type('C.JavaFolder.sample.Nsample');

var result = n.getUrlContents("https://freewebsitetemplates.com/");
print(result);
```

I'm trying to compile javascript code using command prompt but it is showing CLASSNOTFOUNDEXCEPTION.

The command was **jjs sample.js**.Im assuming I did some mistake in Java.type() function.

Can anyone solve this?

Comment: You're trying to run Java from Javascript?  Is it a Java applet?

Comment: yes I'm trying to run java from java script.Mainly I want to call the method inside java class.can you help me with that?

Comment: Is it a server application or a Java applet?

Comment: It is an applet

Comment: I've never done it myself, but a quick search turned up this example and it looks pretty straight-forward... https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/invokingAppletMethodsFromJavaScript.html

Comment: It is a new feature of java 8. Thanks for your response .

Answer (score 0):

This line is the problematic line:

```
var n = Java.type('C.JavaFolder.sample.Nsample');
```

Java.type accepts fully qualified java type name. Based on your Java code, your package seems to be "sample" and class name is "Nsample". So the fully qualified class name would be "sample.Nsample".

You should compile your Java classes and specify the directory in -classpath option (of jjs tool or your java application if you use javax.script API with nashorn).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling Java from JavaScript ,  I tried to call JavaScript from java and worked well.

I created some functions in JavaScript and invoked those functions from Java code.
Following is the code.Hope this helps.

**Test.java:**

```
import javax.script.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;


public class Test{
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{


 ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("Nashorn");
 engine.eval(new FileReader("test.js"));


 Invocable invoke = (Invocable)engine;

 Object res = invoke.invokeFunction("httpGet","https://www.javaworld.com");
 System.out.println(res);


}

}
```

**test.js:**

```
var httpGet = function(theUrl){
var con = new java.net.URL(theUrl).openConnection();
con.requestMethod = "GET";

return asResponse(con);
}

function asResponse(con){
var d = read(con.inputStream);

return d;
}

function read(inputStream){
var inReader = new java.io.BufferedReader(new 
java.io.InputStreamReader(inputStream));
var inputLine;
var response = new java.lang.StringBuffer();

while ((inputLine = inReader.readLine()) != null) {
       response.append(inputLine);
}
inReader.close();
return response.toString();
}
```